# Assign value to array of pointers

Tags: c++

I have array of pointers "item" and i need to assign values to it dynamically all array items have the same value which is last value shown in the second for loop

```
int h = 0;
char* item[6];
char x[] = "sss";

for (h = 0; h < 6; h++)
{
    item[h] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char*));
    sprintf(x, "%s (%d)", "item", h);
    item[h] = &x[0];
    printf("item= %s\r\n", item[h]);
}
for (h = 0; h < 6; h++)
{
    printf("item22222= %s\r\n", item[h]);
}
```

When I run this code I get

```
item= item (0) 
item= item (1) 
item= item (2) 
item= item (3) 
item= item (4) 
item= item (5) 
item22222= item (5) 
item22222= item (5) 
item22222= item (5) 
item22222= item (5) 
item22222= item (5) 
item22222= item (5)
```

Why does the same result repeat in the second loop? I would have thought it would have looked similar to the first loop (`item (1), item (2), ...`). Please help me find the error in my code/logic.

Comment: Are you having a problem?

Comment: @0x499602D2 He's having a problem formatting his code...

Comment: This is not question.

Comment: The output of the code is:

item= item (0)
item= item (1)
item= item (2)
item= item (3)
item= item (4)
item= item (5)
item22222= item (5)
item22222= item (5)
item22222= item (5)
item22222= item (5)
item22222= item (5)
item22222= item (5)

Comment: i need to know the reason why array elements have the same value even in the first for loop are different? and how to make it different in the second for loop?

Comment: @EngHeba, You have undefined behaviour because you're running off the end of the memory you have available to write to. Seriously, use `std::string` and save yourself the trouble of worrying about things like that.

Comment: He is storing the strings in the same buffer `x` (which overflows, yes) - and all the pointers point to that same buffer.

Comment: I'm allocating each array individually and assign value o it.why all pointers point to the same value?

Comment: You are allocating pointers - but they all point to `x` and that doesn't change...

Comment: @Floris: he's allocating pointers yes, but they don't point to anything and he immediately leaks them.

Answer (score 1):

You're allocating a new memory block of size `sizeof(char*)*10` (which, assuming you want enough space for 10 characters, not 10 pointers, should be `sizeof(char)*10`), and then having each index in the `item` array point to a new block of memory in a loop. All is well and good until you overwrite where the `item` array points with the code `item[h]=&x[0]`. This makes every pointer in the item array point the same memory location (`x`). Just sprintf directly into the new memory instead. Also, because you're dealing with strings, make sure to null terminate. Also, you need to make sure you don't write more than 9 characters into your buffer of size 10. Also, unless using c strings is necessary, take chris' advice and use std::string.

```
int h = 0;
char* item[6];

for (h = 0; h < 6; h++)
{
  item[h] = (char*)calloc(20,sizeof(char));
  sprintf(item[h], "item (%d)", h);
  printf("item= %s\n", item[h]);
}
for (h = 0; h < 6; h++)
{
  printf("item2= %s\n", item[h]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you,but when i tried your code below output is displayeditem= (null pointer) item= (null pointer) item= (null pointer) item= (null pointer) item= (null pointer) item= (null pointer) item22222= (null pointer) item22222= (null pointer) item22222= (null pointer) item22222= (null pointer) item22222= (null pointer) item22222= (null pointer)

Comment: not sure what code you're trying, but the edited version above works for me

Comment: This code looks good to me. The error suggests that your `calloc` is unable to allocate even a small block of memory. What platform is this - how much memory do you have? Does the compiler give any error messages? What libraries are you including? What `#include` files? The same questions are equally valid for your issue with my answer which looks similar to this one...

Comment: @Floris there is no errors at all.just printing null pointer with this answer too.I'm including #include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>. I have 1 M for heap and 1M for sram

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't work, because you are making several mistakes.

1) you don't allocate enough space for the buffer `x`.

```
char x[]="sss";
```

This means there will be 3 bytes (plus null) allocated for `x`. But in your `sprintf` you write a larger string to that location. You're lucky it doesn't just segfault (well it didn't for me).

2) you don't copy strings into new space; instead, on every loop you overwrite the same bit of memory (the buffer `x`) with a new string. Since each of the `item[h]` is therefore pointing at the same string, they will all give you the same result in the second loop.

Breaking this second point down a bit (and assuming you made `x` big enough initially, by putting a lot more ssssssssssss in it during initialization):

```
storage buffer x contains    item[h] points to    so when I print it I get
sssssssssssssssss                 nothing
item = item (0)              storage buffer x       item = item(0)
item = item (1)              storage buffer x       item = item(1)
item = item (2)              storage buffer x       item = item(2)
item = item (3)              storage buffer x       item = item(3)
item = item (4)              storage buffer x       item = item(4)
item = item (5)              storage buffer x       item = item(5)
```

When I go around the loop again, item[h] still points to x, which still contains

```
item = item (5)
```

To get this to work you would need to allocate space for each string you want to store (not just pointers to it...):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(void){
  int h = 0;
  char* item[6];
  char *x; 

  for (h = 0; h < 6; h++)
  {
    item[h] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char*));
    x = (char*)malloc(50); // big enough
    sprintf(x, "%s (%d)", "item", h);
    item[h] = x;
    printf("item= %s\r\n", item[h]);
  }

  for (h = 0; h < 6; h++)
  {
    printf("item22222= %s\r\n", item[h]);
  }

}
```

Output:

```
item= item (0)
item= item (1)
item= item (2)
item= item (3)
item= item (4)
item= item (5)
item22222= item (0)
item22222= item (1)
item22222= item (2)
item22222= item (3)
item22222= item (4)
item22222= item (5)
```

Of course you are going to have a hard time freeing the memory allocated like this... but in a small program you can let the cleaning up be done by the operating system on exit.

**EDIT** Since it seems that the `malloc` operation is causing trouble, here is a way to make the program work. It involves "preallocating" the memory used, rather than doing so dynamically. Of course this won't work for very large amounts of data, but then unless and until you discover why you have problems with even a very small `malloc`, you are pretty much out of luck getting a larger program running. So this is for instruction only.

Recall that you are trying to write text to your "item" array. If we make it a 2D array of `char`, and preallocate the data, then we're all set. Trick: the address of `item[h][0]` can be found as either `&item[h][0]` or `item[h]`.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
  int h = 0;
  char item[6][50]; // array of 6 strings of up to 50 characters

  for (h = 0; h < 6; h++)
    {
      sprintf(item[h], "%s (%d)", "item", h);
      printf("item= %s\r\n", item[h]);
    }

  for (h = 0; h < 6; h++)
    {
      printf("item22222= %s\r\n", item[h]);
    }

  }
```

I hope you have more luck with this... it gave me the same output as before.

**Another edit**

Since the underlying problem (`malloc` failing) is still there, we could try to troubleshoot that.  Please try running this program and see what happens:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void){
  char* c;
  int ii;
  for(ii=1;ii<=50;ii++) {
    c = malloc(ii);
    printf("with ii = %d, c is %p\n", ii, c);
    if(c!=NULL) free(c);
    c = malloc(sizeof(int) * ii);
    printf("allocating in chunks of 'sizeof(int)': c is now %p\n", c);
    if (c!=NULL) free(c);
  }
}
```

We should see if / when `malloc` succeeds or fails (it was working in your original snippet, it seems... so now we need to find out when / why it breaks...)

Comment: Done by the OS you mean. AFAIK, compilers don't detect and fix memory leaks for you. Valgrind would be very overrated if the compiler did that and decided to tell you as it did.

Comment: Thank you,but when i tried your code below output is displayeditem= (null pointer)
item= (null pointer)
item= (null pointer)
item= (null pointer)
item= (null pointer)
item= (null pointer)
item22222= (null pointer)
item22222= (null pointer)
item22222= (null pointer)
item22222= (null pointer)
item22222= (null pointer)
item22222= (null pointer)

Comment: That is strange... I just ran this code again and it works perfectly. I included the header files and the output in my latest edit. Please copy/paste this exact file, compile it, and let me know if it gives a problem.

Comment: @chris - fair point; edited answer accordingly (OS cleans up, not compiler).

Comment: @Floris i took it copy and paste but as i mentioned result in null pointer for all.

Comment: How bizarre. Can you try to print out the value of `x` right after the malloc with `printf("x is now %p\n", x);` ? It looks like you have to cast the `50` to a (size_t) or something - but I would have thought that happened automatically. I am stumped ( for now)

Comment: @Floris after adding the mentioned printf,the output is 
x is now 0
          item= (null pointer)
x is now 0
          item= (null pointer)
x is now 0
          item= (null pointer)
x is now 0
          item= (null pointer)
x is now 0
          item= (null pointer)
x is now 0
          item= (null pointer)
item22222= (null pointer)
item22222= (null pointer)
item22222= (null pointer)
item22222= (null pointer)
item22222= (null pointer)
item22222= (null pointer)

Comment: This implied that a trivial amount of memory (50 bytes) could not be allocated. Is there some (low) limit on memory available to a process on your machine? There is a "hard coded" way around this but if we don't I der stand why malloc fails in this simple program you will always get in trouble. Is something else eating all your RAM?

Comment: @Floris Thank you for your help,I have 1MB for heap. Please we are telling me that malloc is failed to allocate memory to "item" and "x".Also i have checked the addresses after allocation and all were different with 4 byte as difference between them

Comment: I have updated my answer one more time - this time using preallocated memory. Let's see if that works...

Comment: @Floris It works with me thank you. So the conclusion of the problem with array of pointers that there is something wrong with mallocor the limited memory,Right?

Comment: Well - there was a problem with your original code, which I and others explained. But the second solution, which should have worked, ran into a problem with `malloc` on your platform, it seems. Glad you have something that works now. Do you understand why?

Comment: @Floris. I know that the solution of 2D is working but actually i really want to make it dynamically that is why i opened that case.i understand your solution and others but what i can't understand why malloc is not working

Comment: Try making a really simple program, allocating and freeing progressively larger chunks of data. I wrote an example at the end of the answer - let me know what it returns.

Comment: @Floris Thank you again for your help.The output for your code is

Comment: with ii = 1, c is 0
allocating in chunks of 'sizeof(int)': c is now 0
with ii = 2, c is 0
allocating in chunks of 'sizeof(int)': c is now 0
with ii = 3, c is 0
allocating in chunks of 'sizeof(int)': c is now 0
with ii = 4, c is 0
allocating in chunks of 'sizeof(int)': c is now 0
with ii = 5, c is 0
allocating in chunks of 'sizeof(int)': c is now 0
with ii = 6, c is 0
allocating in chunks of 'sizeof(int)': c is now 0
with ii = 7, c is 0
allocating in chunks of 'sizeof(int)': c is now 0

------------etc till the end

Comment: Wow - so `malloc` never works at all... Would rebooting your system help? I wonder if memory management is somehow corrupted...?